# Error_Running_Generate_Function_BART_module

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am facing the original error "RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous" while executing the 'generate' function within BART model from transformers. The Python version is 3.6.5, Transformers version 2.3.1
Following is the code used:

```py
# Summary generator model initiation
from transformers import BartTokenizer, BartForConditionalGeneration
bart_model = 'facebook/bart-large-cnn'
sum_tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained(bart_model)
sum_model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(bart_model)

ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE = "My friends are cool but they eat too many carbs."
bart_sum_input_ids = sum_tokenizer.batch_encode_plus([ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE], max_length=1024, return_tensors='pt')
# Generate Summary
summary_ids = sum_model.generate(bart_sum_input_ids['input_ids'], num_beams=4, max_length=5, early_stopping=True)
bart_sum = sum_tokenizer.decode(summary_ids.squeeze(), skip_special_tokens=True)
```

Please help with identifying the issue and solving it.
Full stack trace:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-413492f5e837> in <module>()
      3 
      4 # Generate Summary
----> 5 summary_ids = sum_model.generate(bart_sum_input_ids['input_ids'], num_beams=4, max_length=5, early_stopping=True)
      6 bart_sum = sum_tokenizer.decode(sum_ids.squeeze(), skip_special_tokens=True)

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_no_grad(*args, **kwargs)
     44         def decorate_no_grad(*args, **kwargs):
     45             with self:
---> 46                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     47         return decorate_no_grad
     48 

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/generation_utils.py in generate(self, input_ids, max_length, min_length, do_sample, early_stopping, num_beams, temperature, top_k, top_p, repetition_penalty, bad_words_ids, bos_token_id, pad_token_id, eos_token_id, length_penalty, no_repeat_ngram_size, num_return_sequences, attention_mask, decoder_start_token_id, use_cache, **model_kwargs)
    346         # create attention mask if necessary
    347         # TODO (PVP): this should later be handled by the forward fn() in each model in the future see PR 3140
--> 348         if (attention_mask is None) and (pad_token_id is not None) and (pad_token_id in input_ids):
    349             attention_mask = input_ids.ne(pad_token_id).long()
    350         elif attention_mask is None:

RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

Comment: @cronoik: Sure, but I not allowed to chat yet
and I have already installed the 3.40 version

Comment: @cronoik: how do I install a particular version as when I installed transformers again, it simply installed 3.4

Comment: @cronoik: I installed version 3.3.1 after uninstalling 3.40 but now getting an error while importing BertTokenizer itself which was not the case earlier.
I have updated the problem description above to reflect the current issue. Removed previous comments too

Comment: @cronoik: I fixed the issue and now getting the original issue again on version 3.3.1. Since you are not able to reproduce the error with same code and only difference is python version, I have requested for nimblebox team to update the python version. Will confirm if that fixes the issue. I am updating the above problem statement to original issue

Comment: You are making the same mistake again. You are not giving us a reproducible example. Please add all imports and initialize all variables, so that someone can simply run your code and receives the same error. Yesterday it took me three runs of guessing until I had the same code as you. I am not willing to invest that time again.

Comment: @cronoik: updated the description with all the import libraries used for complete project and import and initialization code used for BART model. Please note that I have used simple text example for summary generation as for it too I am getting the same error as mentioned

Comment: Sorry that I have to rebuke you again for your question, but it is not reproducible and not working. `torch_device` and `sum_ids` are missing. I know what these variables are, but I want you to correct them by yourself. All that I want is that you provide some code that produces the error you get. What you are doing is something else. You have your own code and copy stuff that you consider relevant (and we already saw that I couldn't reproduce it). So please you run the code you give us at least once by yourself in a new python shell and see if it is working and throws the same error.

Comment: ... and just in case you are wondering. When I correct the variables I don't get your error message. `bart_sum` has the value `My friends`.

Comment: @cronoik: I would appreciate if you could help me fix the variables as I am not well versed with BART model. I have been able to successfully use BERT model but obviously not able to understand correctly the variables associated with BART. I am using BART to give summary of top answers from BERT.

Comment: I have modified the code of your question. Could you please copy it and execute it in a shell?

Comment: @cronoik: Thanks a lot for your help thus far :) I tried your code but it's giving me the same error. I had raised this issue with the Nimblebox team as they have provided me with the environment for my project. They have replied to me that this seems to be an issue with the transformer library and have raised the same with developers of transformer package.